# Can someone help explain how to test this AngularJS with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

So I have a simple function:

```
wpApp = angular.module('wpApp', ['ngRoute']);

wpApp.controller("ctrlr", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is the page';
});
```

And I am trying to test it using Jasmine with the following spec:

```
describe("A suite", function() {
    var scope;
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller("controller", {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it("should have the default message", function() {
        return expect(scope.message).toBe('This is the page');
    });
});
```

However, it is not working, as the actual value is coming out to be Undefined.

I am relatively new to AngularJS as well as the ideas of injection. I have been looking around on StackOverflow, in the docs, and in tutorials, and I can't quite seem to figure out exactly what I am doing wrong.

Hopefully it is something small. Can someone help show me what I need to change about my spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load your module:

```
beforeEach(module('wpApp'));
```

Then you need to load the correct controller:

```
$controller("ctrlr", {
    $scope: scope
});
```

Complete code:

```
describe("A suite", function() {
  var scope;

  beforeEach(module('wpApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller("ctrlr", {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it("should have the default message", function() {
    return expect(scope.message).toBe('This is the page');
  });
});
```

Or:

```
describe("A suite", function() {

  var $scope;

  beforeEach(function() {

    module('wpApp');

    inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {

      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      $controller("ctrlr", {
        $scope: $scope
      });
    })
  });

  it("should have the default message", function() {
    return expect($scope.message).toBe('This is the page');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! Could you maybe just quickly explain exactly what the inject function is doing? I understand that the idea is it "injects" the arguments for the function, but why do you give it the two parameters $rootScope and $controller? Do you always give it just those two?

Comment: You're welcome :) Here is an explanation, but if you still have questions just let me know: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject